# How do I display Task #8 in EASy68k?

Tags: easy68k

I want to run TRAP #8 on EASy68k, which by definition, "Returns the time in hundredths of a second since midnight in D1.L." My current code is below. How would I display it?

```
ORG    $1000
  START:                  
   MOVE #8,D0
   TRAP #15

SIMHALT            

END    START
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Task #3 to display a string of numbers in a data register.

Here is an example of what you might do:

```
START:
     MOVE #8,D0
     TRAP #15
     MOVE #3,D0
     TRAP #15
   END START
```